# Explanation of NSURLRequest connection timeout behavior for asynchronous connections

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use an NSURLConnection in my application to load an XML response that can take sometimes a very long time. Right now I'm using a synchronous ASIHTTPRequest in a background thread with a large timeout. I've had a few issues with ASIHTTP (a topic for another day) so I am looking to switch to using NSURLConnection in asynchronous mode instead.

My question is this: When I set a timeout for my NSURLRequest, is that timeout only until data begins to be received by the delegate, or a total timeout for the connection?

Right now with ASIHTTP, it seems that my timeout is for the entire connection (at least for synchronous connections). Sometimes the XML response is too long and the connection fails. I would like to set a timeout only for the actual connection process, wherein afterward there would be an unlimited amount of time to actually download the XML file. I haven't been able to find a concrete answer saying that NSURLConnection works this way, though it seems likely that it does so it could be used for large file downloads.

Please provide a link to support your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [NSURLRequest's timeout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/timeoutInterval) is triggered only if the connection is idle for that interval.  So it sounds like it will do what you want:

> If during a connection attempt the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out.

An alternative is to simply have an NSTimer that triggers after a certain interval -- if it fires before you've started receiving data, call `cancel` on the NSURLConnection.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that settles it.